# Is frequency a scalar quantity?

Tags: vector-spaces

Well, our professor in class posed a question to all of us:
Is frequency a scalar quantity?
The obvious answer, of course, is yes, it is, because it does not have a direction associated with it. But then, a scalar is defined as a coordinate invariant quantity. In the case of frequency this obviously fails (the Doppler shift).
So how do we classify it?

Comment: What are the units for describing frequency?

Comment: inverse of time, s^-1 or Hz

Answer (score 1):

The frequency of a traveling wave is a scalar with respect to Euclidean transformations of space; it is preserved by rotations, translations, and even reflections. It is not a scalar with respect to Galilean, Lorentz or Poincaré transformations of spacetime; boosts of the coordinate system cause a Doppler shift.